# file_put_contents sometimes works, not always

Tags: php, file-put-contents

I have a script that copies the output of twig / email to a tmp file that we need to store for legal purposes. Firstly this was done by using fopen, fwrite, close. That worked for years, all of sudden it stopped working and the files.

Then we changed to using file_put_contents. However that causes the same situation. Fast majority the files are created, however 15-25% the files are not store locally while there is content.

$bytes doesn't output anything when the file_put_contents fails. The error logs don't show anything. Currently there are 324.000 files in the folder, we are bringing that down to 10.000 max.

What is going wrong, or can somebody point me to a different debug approach? See the code below.

Additional info, folder where the files are stored has correct permissions. Script is executed by an cronjob.

```
    try {
    $Contents = $twig->render(stripslashes($TemplateDetails['templateHTML']), $EmailData);
    $Subject = $twig->render(stripslashes($TemplateDetails['templateSubject']), $EmailData);

    $bytes = file_put_contents($serverSettings['root'].'my/tmp/emaillogs/'.$PDFLogFile.'.html', $Contents);

    /*
    $WriteFile = fopen($serverSettings['root'].'my/tmp/emaillogs/'.$PDFLogFile.'.html','w');
    $bytes = fwrite($WriteFile, $Contents);
    fclose($WriteFile);
    */

    echo $Output->getColoredString('Wrote '.$bytes.' to file '. $serverSettings['root'].'my/tmp/emaillogs/'.$PDFLogFile.'.html')."\n";

    // Create the Mailer using your created Transport
    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

    $logger = new \Swift_Plugins_Loggers_ArrayLogger();
    $mailer->registerPlugin(new \Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin($logger));

    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance($Subject)
        ->setFrom(array($ResultSelectEmails[$key]['fromEmail'] => $ResultSelectEmails[$key]['fromName']))
        ->setTo(array($ResultSelectEmails[$key]['toEmail']))
        ->setBody($Contents, 'text/html', 'UTF-8')
    ;

    if (!$mailer->send($message, $errors)) {
        // Dump the log contents
        // NOTE: The EchoLogger dumps in realtime so dump() does nothing for it. We use ArrayLogger instead.
        echo $Output->getColoredString(" - [ERROR] " . $logger->dump(), "red") . "\n";
    }else{
        echo $Output->getColoredString('- [SEND] '.date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'green') . "\n";
    }


}catch (\Exception $exc) {

    $body  = "TemplateId: ".$ResultSelectEmails[$key]['template']."\n";
    $body .= "ShopId: ".$ResultSelectEmails[$key]['shopId']."\n";
    $body .= "--------------------------------------------------------\n";
    $body .= "String Error: ". $exc->getTraceAsString()."\n";
    $body .= "Line: ".$exc->getLine()."\n";
    $body .= "File: ".$exc->getFile()."\n";

    mail('some@email.com', 'TEMPLATE ERROR: '.$ResultSelectEmails[$key]['template'],$body);

    exit;

}
```

Comment: What is in `$PDFLogFile`? Also, I would try to throw an exception when `$bytes == false` and try to know with which files this issue happens.

Comment: $PDFLogFile is the id of the email plus the transaction hash. So in example "1345234-sadfafgasdfasgdsfhggaghf". Those always exist and are always unique.

Comment: if you were using flock with your fopen then you were waiting for the last user to complete.  file_get_contents isn't going to wait, it's just going to say, sorry, there is another user writing there, try later; in which case, your code has to try later.  try putting the data into a temporary storage somewhere, then popping them out of that temporary queue using a scheduled job.

Comment: @WEBjuju 'there is another user writing there' are you referring to the same directory or the same file? Because the last part can't be possible as this is part of a while loop that increases the filename by 1 every round.

Answer (score 1):

Just before

```
$bytes = file_put_contents($serverSettings['root'].'my/tmp/emaillogs/'.$PDFLogFile.'.html', $Contents);
```

put this code - it will help you determine what's up:

```
if (is_writable($serverSettings['root'].'my/tmp/emaillogs/'.$PDFLogFile.'.html')) {
    // no worries, just keep trucking
    // echo 'The file is writable';
} else {
    $body  = "Error writing file: ".$serverSettings['root'].'my/tmp/emaillogs/'.$PDFLogFile.'.html'."\n";
    $body .= "Date Time: ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n";
    $body .= "--------------------------------------------------------\n";
    $body .= "Data to have been written: ".$Contents."\n";

    mail('some@email.com', 'FILE WRITING ERROR', $body);
}
$bytes = file_put_contents($serverSettings['root'].'my/tmp/emaillogs/'.$PDFLogFile.'.html', $Contents);
```

Then you can begin by checking to see if that file exists already or is unwritable.

Comment: I've implemented your script. Some emails have been received with the FILE WRITING ERROR. Strangely, the files have been written.

Comment: "tailing" the files give me results. Could it imply that the files can't be written because of the fact that the disk is to busy?

Comment: ah, the file_put_contents shoudl be inside the is_writable block - my error.  still that's interesting that within that span of a micro second it goes from not writable to writable.  it could be anything that would make the file not writable, i suppose.  why not return to fopen if that was working flawlessly?